# Display product option image Kentico CMS 7

Tags: drop-down-menu, kentico

I need to change the main product picture to the options picture by click in dropdown menu.

code below working perfect with vertical/horizontal radiobuttons and checkboxes but i can't adapt it for ddmenu

in **/CMSModules/Ecommerce/Controls/ProductOptions/ProductOptionSelector.ascx.cs**

```
switch (this.OptionCategory.CategorySelectionType)
        {
            case OptionCategorySelectionTypeEnum.RadioButtonsHorizontal:

                LocalizedRadioButtonList boxListHorizontal = (LocalizedRadioButtonList)this.SelectionControl;
                foreach (ListItem item in boxListHorizontal.Items)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        SKUInfo sku = SKUInfoProvider.GetSKUInfo(ValidationHelper.GetInteger(item.Value, 0));

                        if (sku != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sku.SKUImagePath))
                        {

                           item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "jQuery('.fancyboxProductImg').html('<img alt=\"" + sku.SKUName + "\" src=\"" + URLHelper.ResolveUrl(sku.SKUImagePath) + "\" width=\"240\" height=\"240\" />')");

                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
```

Same code with changed case to ddmenu not working

```
case OptionCategorySelectionTypeEnum.Dropdownlist:

 LocalizedDropDownList dropDown = (LocalizedDropDownList)this.SelectionControl;
  foreach (ListItem item in dropDown.Items)
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` event.

```
item.Attributes.Add("onchange", "js stuff here");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, already tried,  nothing happens, thought something wrong with code above, but item.Text += ... works well for example